# How to select a specific route from an osmnx graph?

Tags: python, networkx, geospatial, osmnx

For context:
First, I downloaded the OSM map I desired to a shapefile format and selected the nodes and edges for the route I needed (specific streets). From there, I exported them to a CSV file so I could import their u,v, osmid info to a python notebook.

Then, I imported the same map in python using `osmnx` and was able to create a subgraph containing just the nodes from my CSV files using `G.subgraph(nodes)`. Like the image here.
[image]

However, I could not do the same for the edges. Does anyone know how to select the desired edges?

P.s.: I do not want to just plot the route. I want to save these nodes and edges in a new graph.

Thank you.

I tried using `G.edges_subgraphs(edges)`. I tried with `edges = [osmid_0,...,osmid_i]` and `edges = [(u_0,v_0),...(u_i,v_i)]`.

`G_mh.edge_subgraph(roads['osmid'])`

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[230], line 1
----> 1 G_mh.edge_subgraph(roads['osmid'])

File ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/networkx/classes/graph.py:1865, in Graph.edge_subgraph(self, edges)
   1827 def edge_subgraph(self, edges):
   1828     """Returns the subgraph induced by the specified edges.
   1829 
   1830     The induced subgraph contains each edge in `edges` and each
   (...)
   1863 
   1864     """
-> 1865     return nx.edge_subgraph(self, edges)

File ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/networkx/classes/function.py:445, in edge_subgraph(G, edges)
    443 if G.is_multigraph():
    444     if G.is_directed():
--> 445         induced_edges = nxf.show_multidiedges(edges)
    446     else:
    447         induced_edges = nxf.show_multiedges(edges)

File ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/networkx/classes/filters.py:69, in show_multidiedges(edges)
     68 def show_multidiedges(edges):
---> 69     edges = {(u, v, k) for u, v, k in edges}
...
     68 def show_multidiedges(edges):
---> 69     edges = {(u, v, k) for u, v, k in edges}
     70     return lambda u, v, k: (u, v, k) in edges

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Comment: Hi, @СергейКох. I'm not sure how to be more specific. My problem is selecting specific edges from a graph and then saving them as a new graph. I included the error I get when trying to use edges_subgraph, if that helps.

Comment: Not sure whether you have already tried this. But you can filter your original geodataframes from the original graph so that the new nodes and edges geodataframes only contain the edges and nodes that you require. Consequently, build a new graph from these two modified geodataframes.

Comment: Using your method, you have to refer to the edges using the identifiers (u,v,key) and not their osmid.

Comment: Also, adding a sample code would help someone to help solve your issue.